# Mixing Boric Acid, Sodium Borate and alcohol

Tags: solvents, precipitation

This is for a liquid detergent that I am developing - when I dissolve boric acid (doesn't fully dissolve though) and then mix it with dissolved sodium borate( also doesn't fully dissolve in water), settling occurs after sometime.
How do firstly dissolve these chemicals and how do I prevent the settling of these after sometime at room temperature?

Comment: Do you respect solubility of substances?

Comment: Please explain...I don't understand

Comment: Explain what you do not understand. Every substance has its solubility limit. If you provide enough water not to reach the limit, the substance can be fully dissolved. Otherwise, it cannot be. // It could be temporarily dissolved at higher temperature, but the raise of solubility with temperature very much depends on the substance. E.g. solubility  of NaCl is almost T independent, while for KNO3 it raises progressively steeply. And it would precipitate back when cooled down to original temperature.

Comment: So I must increase the amount of water when dissolving?

Comment: You must know the thing from everyday life. Take table salt. AFAIK there can be dissolved about 33 g in 100 mL of water. If you provided less than 100 mL for 33 g of salt, it will not fully dissolve, no matter how much you stir. // At 20 deg C, there can be dissolved 4.72 g boric acid/100 mL, or 2.5 g sodium tetraborate decahydrate(borax)/100 mL // See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_table

Comment: You have not said what mass of solids and what volume of water you have used.  If you do not say exactly  what you did, we cannot say what you did wrong or could do better.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I recently dissolved 150grams in 750ml of warm water. In another instance, I dissolved 75grams of Boric acid in 500ml of water, and added 15grams of Sodium Hydroxide. I am begining to see the light - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Before you go further with boric acid and sodium borate, you should know the characteristic properties of them first. Boric acid has the molecular formula $\ce{H3BO3}$ and has a triangular planner structure: $\ce{B(OH)3}$ with the central boron having only six electrons (not fulfilling Octet rule and hence a Lewis acid). According to [this article](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/report/boric-acid-borate-used-excipients-report-published-support-questions-answers-boric-acid-borates-used_en.pdf):

> Its physical appearance is white or almost white crystalline powder or can call it colorless. It is soluble in water and in ethanol (96 per cent), and freely soluble in boiling water to give acidic solution. For example, 3.3% aqueous solution of boric acid shows $\mathrm{pH}$ of $3.8$–$4.8$. Boric acid is also soluble in glycerol (85 per cent).

Thus, for instance, you may use heat to dissolve boric acid well. Yet, you may need to know this: $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of boric acid is $8.92$–$9.24$ that is sensitive to temperature, ionic strength, and concentration (Ref.1). Accordingly,

> The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ varies with concentration because of polymerization above $\pu{0.02 M}$. Boric acid reacts reversibly with alcohols, especially 1,2-diols including carbohydrates, with carboxylic acids, thiols, and amines. These esters/adducts, are also Lewis acids with lower $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values. Boric acid can stabilize some materials while catalyzing the degradation of others.

Thus, the settling you experience must be due to the polymerization of boric acid solution:

[image: Polymerization in boric acid]

[image: Polymerization in boric acid-2]

Finally, boric acid and/or borate can easily undergoes esterification with alcohol functions (Ref.2). For example,

[image: esterification with alcohol]

---

**References:**

1. Antonio Lopalco, Angela A. Lopedota, Valentino Laquintana, Nunzio Denora, Valentino J. Stella, "Boric Acid, a Lewis Acid With Unique and Unusual Properties: Formulation Implications," *Journal of Pharmaceutical Sciences* **2020**, *109(8)*, 2375-2386 (ODI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.xphs.2020.04.015).
2. Supachok Tanpichai, Farin Phoothong, and Anyaporn Boonmahitthisud, "Superabsorbent cellulose-based hydrogels cross-liked with borax," *Scientific Reports* **2022**, *12*, 8920 (12 pages) (ODI: https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-022-12688-2).

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me.